# VBA - Find the next empty row in a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

How can i find the next empty row in a workbook where i want to paste some content i copied early in another workbook.
This is what i get now:

```
Sub Retânguloarredondado1_Click()

Dim InputFile As Workbook
Dim OutputFile As Workbook
Dim Inputpath As String
Dim Outputpath As String '
Dim TP As Worksheet
Dim copyRange As Range
Dim pasteRange As Range
Dim cel As Range
Dim test As Range
Dim MyAr() As Variant
Dim n As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

' Set path for Input & Output
fileInputpath = "C:\Users\Nuno Bonaparte\Desktop\"
Outputpath = "C:\Users\Nuno Bonaparte\Desktop\"

'## Open both workbooks first:
Set InputFile = ActiveWorkbook
Set OutputFile = Workbooks.Open(Outputpath & "file2.xlsm")
Set TP = OutputFile.Worksheets("Folha1")
Set copyRange = InputFile.Sheets("file2").Range("A1,B3,C5,D7,E9")
Set pasteRange = OutputFile.Sheets("Folha1").Range("A1")



'~~> Get the count of cells in that range
        n = copyRange.Cells.Count

        '~~> Resize the array to hold the data
        ReDim MyAr(1 To n)

        n = 1

        '~~> Store the values from that range into
        '~~> the array
        For Each cel In copyRange.Cells
            MyAr(n) = cel.Value
            n = n + 1
        Next cel


'Now, paste to OutputFile worksheet:
OutputFile.Sheets("Folha1").Activate
pasteRange.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(MyAr)).Value = _
    MyAr

'Close InputFile & OutputFile:
'InputFile.Close
OutputFile.Save
OutputFile.Close

End Sub
```

The code works fine, but i would like to find the  next empty row and paste the new content

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
With OutputFile.Sheets("Folha1").Range("A:A").Find(vbNullString, [A1])
    .Resize(1, Ubound(MyAr)) = MyAr
End With
```

Above code looks for the first empty cell after A1 and apply resize and assign value in that cell.
Is this what you're trying? You can also [check this out to give you more idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba). HTH.